# Vue-Bootstrap b-form-input state on blur rather than load

Tags: validation, vuejs2, blur, bootstrap-vue

I'm using Vue-Bootstrap and I have a `b-form-input` in my component that is a password. I check the validation on this input for the password being at least 8 characters long:

```html
<b-form-group
        label="Password: (8 characters minimum)"
        minlength="8"
        class="text-left  mt-3"
      >
        <b-form-input
          v-model="form.password"
          type="password"
          name="password"
          placeholder="Enter Your Password"
          :state="passwordState"
          pattern=".{8,}"
          description="please enter a password "
          title="Password should be at least 8 characters long"
          required
        ></b-form-input>
        <b-form-invalid-feedback :state="passwordState">
          Your password must be at least 8 characters long.
        </b-form-invalid-feedback>
      </b-form-group>
      <b-form-group
        was-validated
        label="Confirm Password:"
        class="text-left  mt-3"
      >
        <b-form-input
          type="password"
          v-model="form.confirmpassword"
          placeholder="Confirm Your Password"
          required
          :state="confirmPasswordState"
          pattern=".{8,}"
        ></b-form-input>
        <b-form-invalid-feedback :state="confirmPasswordState">
          Your confirmed password must be exactly the same as your password
          field.
        </b-form-invalid-feedback>
      </b-form-group>
```

```js
 computed: {
    confirmPasswordState() {
      return this.form.password == this.form.confirmpassword &&
        this.form.confirmpassword != ""
        ? true
        : false;
    },
    passwordState() {
      return this.form.password.length >= 8 ? true : false;
    },
  },
```

I only want this state validation to show up on blur and not on load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do this is to add a flag in data to track whether an input has blurred, and then make validation conditional based on that flag.

1. Add `passwordHasBlurred: false` to `data()`
2. Add `@blur="passwordHasBlurred = true"` to both of your `<b-form-input>`s:

   - ```html
     <b-form-input
        ...
        @blur="passwordHasBlurred = true"
     >
     ```
3. Adjust your computed validation functions to return `null` when `passwordHasBlurred` is `false`. [This tells Bootstrap-Vue to display no validation state](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/form-input#contextual-states) on either input before one is blurred.

   - ```js
     passwordState() {
       return this.passwordHasBlurred
         ? this.form.password.length >= 8
           ? true
           : false
         : null;
     },
     ```
   - ```js
     confirmPasswordState() {
       return this.passwordHasBlurred 
         ? this.form.password == this.form.confirmpassword &&
          this.form.confirmpassword != "" 
          ? true 
          : false
         : null;
     },
     ```

And here's a runnable example! (Hidden because of its size):

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      form: {
        password: '',
        confirmPassword: '',
      },
      passwordHasBlurred: false,
    }
  },
  computed: {
    confirmPasswordState() {
      return this.passwordHasBlurred 
        ? this.form.password == this.form.confirmpassword &&
         this.form.confirmpassword != "" 
         ? true 
         : false
        : null;
    },
    passwordState() {
      return this.passwordHasBlurred
        ? this.form.password.length >= 8
          ? true
          : false
        : null;
    },
  },
  methods: {
    reset() {
      this.form.password = '';
      this.form.confirmPassword = '';
      this.passwordHasBlurred = false;
    },
  },
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<!-- Add Vue and Bootstrap-Vue to snippet -->
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" /><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.css" /><script src="//polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es2015%2CIntersectionObserver" crossorigin="anonymous"></script><script src="//unpkg.com/vue@2/dist/vue.min.js"></script><script src="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>

<template id="app">
  <div>
    <b-form-group
      label="Password: (8 characters minimum)"
      minlength="8"
      class="text-left  mt-3"
    >
      <b-form-input
        v-model="form.password"
        type="password"
        name="password"
        placeholder="Enter Your Password"
        :state="passwordState"
        pattern=".{8,}"
        description="please enter a password "
        title="Password should be at least 8 characters long"
        required
        @blur="passwordHasBlurred = true"
      ></b-form-input>
      <b-form-invalid-feedback :state="passwordState">
        Your password must be at least 8 characters long.
      </b-form-invalid-feedback>
      </b-form-group>
      <b-form-group
        label="Confirm Password:"
        class="text-left  mt-3"
      >
      <b-form-input
        type="password"
        v-model="form.confirmpassword"
        placeholder="Confirm Your Password"
        required
        :state="confirmPasswordState"
        pattern=".{8,}"
        @blur="passwordHasBlurred = true"
      ></b-form-input>
      <b-form-invalid-feedback :state="confirmPasswordState">
        Your confirmed password must be exactly the same as your password
        field.
      </b-form-invalid-feedback>
    </b-form-group>
    <br>
    <b-btn variant="outline-secondary" @click="reset">
      Reset
    </b-btn>
  </div>
</template>
```

If you want or need to track each input's blurring separately, just add another property to data for tracking and adjust the computed property and event handlers accordingly.